# what should i do for working with closedxml correctly in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, using-directives

I'm using gridview on my webform and I want to export data from SQL server to excel using asp.net c#, and I'm using ClosedXML.Excel but the error is

> The type or namespace name 'ClosedXML' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How could I remove this?

Comment: "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: may be but problem is that i dont know how to resolve this

Comment: You have to reference the DLL

Comment: Or import the appropriate namespace.

Comment: how? this is what i'm asking

Answer (score 7):

It because you have not installed the package therefore you don't have the appropriate DLLs. Due to not having the DLLs you are receiving this error. Firstly you will need to install the package using NuGet as mentioned **[here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/)** and then reference it accordingly. To install the package just do

```
Install-Package ClosedXML
```

Once you have installed the package just do

```
using ClosedXML;
```

Comment: This can be done (in the current 2022 Community edition of MS Visual Studio) on the Tools menu, 'NuGet Package Manager', and after that the 'using ClosedXML' statement in the code will take effect.