# Export GridView using ClosedXML library

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, closedxml

I am using `GridView` on my page markup and I want to export data from MySQL database to excel using asp.net c#, and I am using [ClosedXML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiOK7.png) but the error is :

> The type or namespace name 'ClosedXML' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried suggestions on Google without success.

Please help me, thak you in advance.

My code below.

In `Bin` folder on my project I have this :

[image]

In `packages.config` I have this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AjaxControlToolkit" version="15.1.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="ClosedXML" version="0.76.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" version="2.5" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="DocumentFormat.OpenXmlSDK" version="2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="ExcelDataReader" version="2.1.2.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="iTextSharp" version="5.5.7" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

In `web.config` I have this:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
    <add assembly="Office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
    <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add assembly="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

**#Edit 01**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using ClosedXML;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
```

**#Edit 02**

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507242/what-should-i-do-for-working-with-closedxml-correctly-in-asp-net

Comment: Do your code have `using ClosedXML;`?

Comment: @Irshad the package is installed plese see the question and the attachament image.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the package?

Comment: @Raidri, Yes I have tried uninstall and reinstall the package without success, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There may be following reasons;

1. You have not installed the package therefore you don't have the appropriate DLLs - Install `ClosedXML` from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/)
2. Missing `using` directive in code

   `using ClosedXML;`
3. Check whether you project is set to `.Net 4.0 Client Profile`.If so change to `.Net 4.0`

Comment: PM> Install-Package ClosedXML
Attempt to resolve the dependency 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml (= 2.5)'.
'ClosedXML 0.76.0' already installed.
There is already a reference to MyProject 'ClosedXML 0.76.0'.

Comment: Check for 3rd option. What is your project's target framework?